# applicationContext.getBean() with legacy applications

Tags: spring

I'm trying to integrate spring into a legacy application built on J2EE + RMI.

I've seen a tonne of posts on StackOverflow regarding avoiding the use of context.getBean().  This makes sense to me.  What does not make sense to me is how you can have spring generate context specific beans that require information from your code to obtain the bean.  I haven't seen a single post actually explain this; maybe my search terms are bad.

For example, how do I get a person object for a specific person that just logged in?  Clearly I don't want to define a spring bean for every person in the database with bean names such as person1, person2, personN, etc.

Up until now I've just been using a static utility factory method to obtain the context, and then call getBean() on that context; but I've really wanted a better way, as this not real IoC.

Should I use spring only for the independent components/services that don't need specific data pieces, and then pass the data to them when I use them?

Comment: I've re-worded a little bit, in the hopes it's more clear.  I have very limited knowledge on spring.  I've been using it for a variety of things so far, mostly configuration related stuff, using @Value for example.  So, I may not be asking the question quite right.  If anyone can help me clarify the question, and then answer it, that would be cool.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken a course on spring, but it didn't really get into these sorts of details.  I decided that I was going to just wade through the entire spring core documentation.  Lo and behold it's quite near the top...

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-metadata

> Typically, one does not configure fine-grained domain objects in the container, because it is usually the responsibility of DAOs and business logic to create and load domain objects. However, you can use Spring’s integration with AspectJ to configure objects that have been created outside the control of an IoC container.

That is why it felt so clunky, cause I shouldn't be doing that.

I will consider how I'm going to manage all of this in a rather legacy app with tight coupling, and possibly update this post to explain some solutions.